# SPAN tag groups TR tags but SPAN is not parent of TR

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, html

i'm grouping `TR` tags using a `SPAN` tag. Navigation from the `TR` tag to the `SPAN` tag using the parent node isn't possible, although the parent tag is really the `SPAN` tag. Instead a `TBODY` (which is not a tag within the html ) is detected. Why is this so? In IE it works fine but not in chrome.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you mean.

Comment: thanks, i already have a workaround for this problem. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even you don't add the `<tbody>` tag, the DOM still add it (you can see it in a developer tool like Google Chrome Dev tool or Firebug for Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

W3C recommends using (multiple)TBODY tags:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

That your SPAN doesn't work in all browsers is not surprising, a SPAN is not a valid child-element for a TABLE.
Run your page through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and you'll see

Comment: I thought SPAN can be used to group anything anywhere. However in IE it can be used as a child element in a TABLE. If TR tags are childtags of a SPAN tag, the parent of such a TR tag is of course the SPAN tag. In chrome the parent is a tag that even doesn't exist within the html, in this case TBODY. This is wierd. Thanks for your answer.